# How to count the occurences of different characters and return all of them as a table

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Here's the exact question:

`COUNT-BASES` counts the number of bases of each type in
    either single- or double-stranded DNA and returns the result
    as a table.

```
(COUNT-BASES '((G C) (A T) (T A) (C G))) should return
((A 2) (T 2) (G 2) (C 2))
(COUNT-BASES '(A G T A C T C T)) should return
((A 2) (T 3) (G 1) (C 2)).
```

I've written a function my-count that returns the occurences of one char but can't figure out how to apply this for all 4 letters (A T G C) and return as a table.

```
;returns the count of a base (a) from a list (L)
(defun my-count (a L)
  (cond ((null L) 0)
        ((equal a (car L)) (+ 1 (my-count a (cdr L))))
        (t (my-count a (cdr L)))))
```

Comment: Common Lisp has a number of functions for working with association lists, do you know how to use them?

Comment: Your code only works with single-stranded DNA, not double-stranded.

Comment: You can simply call your function 4 times, once for each letter, and create a table of the results.

Answer (score 1):

I'd handle the flat case (single stranded, i. e. a list of bases) first.  Loop over the list and count each base into a hash table:

```
(defun count-bases (dna)
  (let ((counts (make-hash-table)))
    (dolist (base dna counts)
      (incf (gethash base counts 0)))))
```

Now, it might be double stranded, so each element is not a base, but a list of bases.  But we already know how to handle a list of bases.  In order to count into a single table, make it possible to pass it into the recursive call:

```
(defun count-bases (dna &optional (counts (make-hash-table)))
  (dolist (base-or-pair dna counts)
    (if (symbolp base-or-pair)
        (incf (gethash base-or-pair counts 0))
        (count-bases base-or-pair counts))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A purely imperative version of the code could be as follows:

```
(defun count-bases (bases)
  (let ((atgc (vector 0 0 0 0)))
    (dolist (dna bases (map 'list #'list #(a t g c) atgc))
      (dolist (base (if (listp dna) dna (list dna)))
        (incf (svref atgc (position base #(a t g c))))))))
```

1. Create a vector of 4 elements, that store counters for all bases.
2. Iterate over all entries in the list, and iterate over all bases in each entry: typically this is done with `alexandria:ensure-list`, but here it is written in plain.
3. Find the position of each base in the literal vector `#(a t g c)`, a vector of symbols. Use the returned position to increment the associated counter.
4. Finally (last form in [`DOLIST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dolist.htm)), build the return value in the expected format:

   [`MAP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm) over both `#(a t g c)` and the counter vector `atgc`, build a `'list` by applying the function `#'list` to each pair of elements taken from both sequences: for example, the first iteration visits `a` and the counter for base `a`, and calls `#'list` on them, which builds `(a ...)`, where ... is the actual value.